# Commerce price difference for specific country

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a fairly simple shop with one product. I would like to be able to adjust the price of the product (increase it by around 5%) for customers from one specific country.
I have some price changes applied by user group in promotions already but I don't see any options to do the same by country.
Any ideas what the best way to tackle this is?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to add the surcharge as a shipping cost?

Comment: It's a digital product so we currently don't use shipping costs but that's a great idea @JamesSmith I'll investigate that. Thanks